# SafeArgs generated classes (Directions/Args) are not recognized by lint in AS 3.5

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I'm migrating several apps to use the Navigation Component, and I ran into a problem - the Directions/Args classes generated by the `android-safe-args-gradle-plugin` are not being recognized in Android Studio.

Code demonstrating this problem is located at [github.com/wooldridgetm/android-navigation.git](https://github.com/wooldridgetm/android-navigation.git), but crux of the matter is, in the code below, **HomeFragmentDirections** isn't recognized. This is taken from the class `HomeFragment`, lines 76 - 82.

```
val b2 = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.navigate_action_button)
b2.setOnClickListener {
    // PROBLEM: HomeFragmentDirections isn't recognized.
    val action = HomeFragmentDirections.nextAction()
    // PROBLEM: results in Unresolved reference: flowStepNumber
    // action.flowStepNumber = 1
    findNavController().navigate(action)
}
```

I know what the documentation says & I know that class `HomeFragmentDirections` is being generated by the plugin & is located at app/**build**/**generated**/**source**/**navigation-args**/**debug**/code/example/android/codelabs/navigation, but it is not recognized by AS.

I also know that this did work pre-v2 of the plugin...but it's not working now & I can't even get a simple example to behave as expected.

Any ideas on what's wrong?

**BACKGROUND**

I'm using AS 3.5 on MacOS Mojave, 10.14.6.

Project `build.gradle` dependencies:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.1.0"
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50"
```

App `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'

dependencies {
  // Navigation
  def nav_version = "2.1.0"
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem with AS 4.2, Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

The reason Android Studio/Lint wasn't "seeing" these classes was BIAD (b/c I'm a dummy).

I excluded the `build` folder in the **Project Panel** via **Preferences** > **Editor** > **File Types** > **Ignore files and folders**.

In any event, removing the `build` folder from **Ignore files and folders** did the trick.

[image: Preferences > Editor > File Types]

Comment: I have the same problem with AS 4.2 Beta 6. All classes related to SafeArgs or Directions are not recognized and shows error, but compiles. Your solution didn't work for me. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Select the *Project* view in the project tab, so you can see the actual folders. You'll notice the *app/build* folder is oranged out, which means it's being excluded. Simply right click > Mark directory as > Cancel exclusion, then right click again > Mark directory as > Sources root. The folder will be blued out like the java folder and AS should recognize the generated classes.

Although I'm not sure I believe all the code you're gonna use is actually in *app/build/generated*, so you could be more specific marking that one as the sources root instead. [So it should look something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVNq6.png)

Comment: This coused redeclareation issues for me. Instead, I've marked navigatin-args->debug as Generated sources root

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with actions which were clearly added in the navigation graph not 'autocompleting' or showing an option to import in the kotlin class trying to access them, even with the correct import added manually.

For me the fix was simply to to rebuild the project and they automatically appeared then.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue in Navigation API, Apparently, They have fixed this issue in **2.5.0-rc02** version.

Please refer to [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/233119646) for more details.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).